# How to integrate model functions in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a model called UNIT.  I want to create a function that gets certain things from the model based on conditions.

```
class Unit (models.Model):
    HType = (
        ('HQ', 'IFT Headquarters'),
        ('JTF', 'Joint Task Force'),
        ('GEO', 'Geographic Theater'),
        ('SHIP', 'Federation Vessel Chapter')
    )
    Unit_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Hull_number = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Hull_type = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=HType)
    Parent_unit = models.ForeignKey("self", blank=True, null=True)
    Class = models.ForeignKey(Class)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    Member = models.ManyToManyField(Member, through='MemberUnit')
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')
    City = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    State = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='')
    Zip = models.IntegerField()

    def getCO(self):
        from ifthq import models
        Posn = models.Position.objects.get(Position_name="Commanding Officer")
        CPosn = models.ClassPosition.objects.get(unit_class=self.Class, unit_position=Posn)
        MbrU = models.MemberUnit.objects.get(Unit=self, Position=CPosn)
        MbrR = models.MemberRank.objects.filter(Member=MbrU.Member).latest("Date_Effective")
        CO = MbrR.Rank.Short_name + ' ' + MbrU.Member.first_name + ' ' + MbrU.Member.last_name
        return CO

    def getstaff(self, position):
        from ifthq import models
        Posn = models.Position.objects.get(Position_name=position)
        CPosn = models.ClassPosition.objects.get(unit_class=self.Class, unit_position=Posn)
        MbrU = models.MemberUnit.objects.get(Unit=self, Position=CPosn)
        MbrR = models.MemberRank.objects.filter(Member=MbrU.Member).latest("Date_Effective")
        XO = MbrR.Rank.Short_name + ' ' + MbrU.Member.first_name + ' ' + MbrU.Member.last_name
        return XO

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Unit_name
```

Unit.getCO works, Unit.getstaff() does not.

Here's the view:

```
@login_required
def unit_view(request, unit):
    try:
        unit_id = models.Unit.objects.get(Q(Hull_number=unit) | Q(Unit_name=unit))
    except unit_id.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Poll does not exist")
    if unit_id.Hull_type == "GEO":
        ship_count = models.Unit.objects.filter(Parent_unit=unit_id).filter(Hull_type="SHIP").count()
        tf_count = models.Unit.objects.filter(Parent_unit=unit_id).filter(Hull_type="JTF").count()
        fenlisted = models.Subscription.objects.rankset("E").active().filter(Member__in=models.MemberUnit.objects.filter(Unit__Parent_unit=unit_id).values("Member")).count()
        fofficer = models.Subscription.objects.rankset("O").active().filter(Member__in=models.MemberUnit.objects.filter(Unit__Parent_unit=unit_id).values("Member")).count()
        fcivilian = models.Subscription.objects.rankset("C").active().filter(Member__in=models.MemberUnit.objects.filter(Unit__Parent_unit=unit_id).values("Member")).count()
    else:
        ship_count = 0
        tf_count = 0
        fenlisted = 0
        fofficer = 0
        fcivilian = 0
    enlisted = models.Subscription.objects.rankset("E").active().filter(Member__in=models.MemberUnit.objects.unitcrew(unit_id).values("Member")).count()
    officer = models.Subscription.objects.rankset("O").active().filter(Member__in=models.MemberUnit.objects.unitcrew(unit_id).values("Member")).count()
    civilian = models.Subscription.objects.rankset("C").active().filter(Member__in=models.MemberUnit.objects.unitcrew(unit_id).values("Member")).count()
    context = {'fcivilian': fcivilian, 'fofficer': fofficer,
               'fenlisted': fenlisted, 'fleet': ship_count,
               'jtf': tf_count, 'enlisted': enlisted,
               'officer': officer, 'civilian': civilian,
               'Unit': unit_id
               }
    return render(request, 'unit.html', context)
```

in the template, I'm using `variable.getCO` and `variable.getstaff("Executive Officer"), and I may have a return of 1 or more rows expressed in a for loop.

getCO works, getstaff("Executive Officer") does not.  How do I have getstaff work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling a model method with parameters inside the template, which will be not possible in this way.

You should define a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) as follows and use that:

```
@register.filter
def getstaff(obj, position):
   # your code remains here
   # instead of self use obj and at the end return value
```

Now use it on your template:

```
{{ variable|getstaff:"Executive Officer" }}
```

Comment: Hi Serjik.  This is awesome.  Where does it go?  Is it still part of the defined model class?  meaning leave it there? or where does it go?

Comment: The app should contain a templatetags directory, at the same level as models.py, views.py, etc. If this doesn’t already exist, create it - don’t forget the __init__.py file to ensure the directory is treated as a Python package.

Comment: Genius.  Works like a champ.  Thank you so much.